# EJB webservice, entity is not mapped error

Tags: java, web-services, hibernate, jpa, ejb-3.1

I have entity class User

```
@Entity(name = "user")
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;

@Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
private String email;

  /** skipped **/
```

And stateless EJB DAO class(I am using jpa/hibernate) with method

```
@Override
public User findByEmail(String name) {
    TypedQuery<User> query = entityManager.createQuery("from User where email= :email", User.class);
    query.setParameter("email", name);
    return query.getSingleResult();
}
```

When I execute this method from page(using jsf), it works fine. The problem occurse when I execute this method from WebService EJB bean. I've got following exception

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: User is not mapped [from User where email= :email]
```

My web service is very simple:

```
@Stateless(name = "webServiceBean")
@WebService(serviceName = "webService")
public class MyWebService{

@EJB
private UserDao dao;

public String findUser(String email) {
    return dao.findByEmail(email);
}
```

}

Application is deployed on JBoss7. I am using EJB 3.1 and hibernate 4.3
Does anybody knows what is the reason of this exception? And why it occurs only in WebService?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Make sure `User`, along with the package name, is listed in hibernate config file.
2. Either use just `@Entity` or `@Entity(name = "User")`. You have named your entity as `user` but in your query trying to refer to it as `User`.

---

Check the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Entity.html#name()) for the `@Entity`'s `name` attribute.

> public abstract java.lang.String name
>
> (Optional) The entity name. Defaults to the unqualified name of the entity class. **This name is used to refer to the entity in queries.** The name must not be a reserved literal in the Java Persistence query language.

Comment: Changing User to lower case in query fixed problem. Thanks.